# Gear slipping on Cannondale Habit

Tags: chain, repair, cassette

I have a Habit ebike with 1,700 kms on it. I was having slippage on gears and my bike dealer fitted a new chain and new cable but now it is worse.

When looking at the derailleur in the 2nd gear from top (12 gears) I noticed that the chain engages only about 90 degrees whereas on my Marin with similar gears the chain covers about 160 degrees. I have much more mileage on the Marin and a lot more climbing without ever changing chain or cassette.  The cassette on Cannondale does not seem to be worn. Would the small contact with cassette be causing slippage?

Comment: If you could post some photos of your rear derailleur/cassette/chain that would help us picture things. Also, what exactly do you mean by slippage - do you see slippage, feel slippage, hear slippage, and where exactly, and under what conditions?  Also, since the ebike is probably heavier than your Marin, and uses narrower gears(x12 vs x?), the drivetrain will wear faster.

Comment: post pictures of the spot where it looks like there's not enough chain wrap

Comment: @Armand Point of information - the greatly improved metallurgy used in higher gear count drivetrains compensates for the narrower width. Drivetrain life is comparable across speed counts and 12s may actually be better.

Comment: @MaplePanda Good to know - I should have figured there might be some magic metallurgy involved!

Comment: @Armand Here’s the article: https://cyclingtips.com/2019/12/the-best-bicycle-chain-durability-and-efficiency-tested/#8-9-10-11-12-speed

Comment: I can't find a way to add photos.

Comment: Click "Edit" above, click the mountain top image in the "Body" box, and add a link.

Comment: I brought it back to shop today and had it adjusted so that it has more engagment on smaller sprockets but more difficult to move onto bigest sprocket which I never use anyway. I might get a new cassette which does not have as wide a range. The smaller sprockets (higher gear) have some wear.

Comment: Thanks for help. I still cant figure out how to add photo.

Answer (score 1):

If the b-gap adjustment and chain length are right, it is probably not being caused by limited chain wrap. That said, those things have to be right or close to right, and if the b-gap was extremely poorly adjusted you could maybe get something like this to happen.

Ebikes are hard on drivetrains and 1700km is enough for drivetrain parts to start being worn out. If you're favoring the smaller cogs because it's a 1x MTB being used on the road, that is defintely enough to wear out the small end.

The slippage being worse when the chain was changed and nothing else is a symptom of worn out drivetrain parts (cassette or chainring). If it was exactly the same after the new chain, slip in the freehub body would be one of the things needing investigating (it can feel like the chain slipping), but that's probably not what's going on if it's actually worse.